# Adding a attribute to active job in before hooks rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

I am about to implement retry logic for jobs and the retry logic will be based on the number of attempts for the particular job. so we are planning to keep the number of attempts as one of the job's attributes.

Here is a way to achieve this,

```
# Set no. of attempts in the job data
  def serialize
    super.merge('no_of_attempts' => (@no_of_attempts || 0) + 1)
  end

  # Get no. of attempts from the job data
  def deserialize(job_data)
    super
    @no_of_attempts = job_data['no_of_attempts']
  end
```

Storing the attempts count in job attribute and limit the retries count based on that attribute.

This works well while using the `perform_later`. I know when enqueuing jobs only serialize method will be called.

But in one of my cases, I am restricted to use the `perform_now`. I hope that adding an additional argument to the job should be done by using the active job `before_perform` method but not sure how to add a param. Any suggestions, please.

Comment: I think you should try SideKiq that build on ActiveJob specification and which has more features.

Comment: ActiveJob already handles retries, have you checked the `retry_on` configuration? https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#retrying-or-discarding-failed-jobs